# Fluent NHibernate, dynamically change Table of mapping?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate

with fluent nhibernate, is there a way to dynamically switch the table of a mapping at runtime?

For example:

```
public class XYClassMap : ClassMap<XY>
{
  public XYClassMap( )
  {
    Table("XYTable");
    Id(d => d.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
    Map(d => d.Value);
    (...)
```

Given that there are multiple plugins, each of them uses this one class, but they need to work with different tables. I am looking for something like this:

```
public class XY {
  public string Tablename {get; set;}
}

public class XYClassMap : ClassMap<XY>
{
  public XYClassMap( )
  {
    Table(Tablename);
    Id(d => d.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
    Map(d => d.Value);
    (...)
```

So every action method could work with the same class and only would need to set this one property "Tablename".

Thanks for any help,

Steffen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mappings are compiled on application startup, and once that's happened they cannot be changed.

If your plugins use different tables, then by definition they aren't the same entities (and thus the same mappings). If your plugins all define different tables which all have the same structure, then you need separate mappings but you might be able to abstract the actual definitions.

Something like this, perhaps: each plugin defines it's own mapping for this table, which derive from an abstract class containing the actual mappings except for the table name.

```
public abstract class PluginMap<T> : ClassMap<T> where T : IPlugin
{
  public PluginMap()
  {
    Id(d => d.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
    Map(d => d.Value);
  }
}

public class PluginOneMap : PluginMap<PluginOne>
{
  public PluginOneMap()
  {
    Table("PluginOne");
  }
}

public class PluginTwoMap : PluginMap<PluginTwo>
{
  public PluginTwoMap()
  {
    Table("PluginTwo");
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could define them as subclasses in an table-per-subclass or table-per-inheritance-hierarchy.

Comment: This is something I tried (failed at first and gave up due to schedule pressure). Thanks very much, i will check it out as soon as I´m at my development PC and will come back here ;) Great work btw, keep it up!

Comment: Fantastic! It works perfectly. I used your idea of mapping the generic base class, import all models from plugins via MEF and made the plugin repository fetch the data like this:

public List<T> GetData<T>(int id, string modelClassname)  where T : IData
    {
      return session.Linq<T>(modelClassname).Where(d => d.ObjectId == id).ToList();      
    }

Thanks for your inspiration, I´ll accept immediately :)